# assign column values to a variable in mssql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables

I am trying to assign all the table names of a schema to a variable. Later, I wish to create an update trigger for each table.
I am extracting the tables using :

```
select table_name from information_schema.tables;
```

when I do the following, I get null values:

```
declare @tablename nvarchar(max)
select table_name = @tablename from information_schema.tables;
```

I am using mssql in SSMS2016, can someone please tell me how I can assign the table names to a variable?

Comment: For assignment it's `@Variable = ColumnName` not `ColumnName = @Variable`. The latter would be `ColumnName = Alias`.

Comment: You *can't* use MySQL with SSMS. In any case, SSMS is just a client tool and its version doesn't affect the SQL code you execute

Comment: Also, don't declare `@tablename` as an `nvarchar(MAX)`; use `sysname`. That datatype is specifically designed for store object names, and is a synonym for `nvarchar(128) NOT NULL`. (*Note: The `NOT NULL` property of the datatype has no effect on variables, but will when used in a column.)

Comment: As for the query, is there a typo perhaps? This returns the contents of `@tablename` once for every table. Since `@tablename` is NULL, you'll get back nulls named `Table_name`. What are you trying to do? Why not just use `select table_name from information_schema.tables;` ?

Comment: Even if you wanted to assign the table names to a variable, you can't assign *multiple* values to a single string variable. You'll have to create a table variable and store the results there

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me. Creating an update trigger on every table sounds like a design idea that is less than ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a really good question, if it is a good idea to create a trigger for each and any table, but - whenever I need to **create** statements - I suggest this:

```
select CONCAT('CREATE TRIGGER ',QUOTENAME(CONCAT(table_name,'_trigger')),' ON ',QUOTENAME(table_name),' AFTER UPDATE AS BEGIN PRINT ''yeah!''; END',CHAR(13),CHAR(10),'GO' )
from information_schema.tables
where TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE';
```

Send the output to text and you get:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [SomeTable_trigger] ON [SomeTable] AFTER UPDATE AS BEGIN PRINT 'yeah!'; END
GO
CREATE TRIGGER [Another_trigger] ON [Another] AFTER UPDATE AS BEGIN PRINT 'yeah!'; END
GO
... more of this...
GO
...
```

The next step was to copy all these statements to a new query window and adapt them to your needs.

Comment: if you write the result of this concat in an variable, you can use execute sp_executesql after creating those statements

Comment: @Isparia My "normal" way of doing was 1) write this into a table variable and 2) use a `CURSOR` to work it down. But in the given situation I assume, that the triggers content might not be the same in any case and that the OP wants to store these statements as a normal script (for futuer usage).

Comment: When I generate sql commands using this idea, i get the error - create trigger must be the only statement in the batch. I tried adding GO at the start and end of the concat statement but the error isn't resolved yet.

Comment: @Jenna Go must be on its own line. That is, why I wrote "send it to text output" The grid output will omit line breaks...

Comment: does it have a limit on the number of characters? It's cutting off the end of the cmd

Comment: @Shnugo also, can you please share how would have done this using a cursor ( as you mentioned in a comment)

Comment: @Jenna In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39260384/5089204) you'll find a template...]